# Multiple For & Next VBA function

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying create a short code that will hopefully save some typing time.

What I'm trying to achieve is a VBA function that inserts a changing value into each cell in column A.

The value can be broken down with the prefix of "Wk" (short for week) followed by "17" (this is the year) followed by a week number "01". This is repeated 7 times for each day of the week before rolling onto the next week and inevitably the next year and so forth.

Example:
Cell A1 = Wk1701
Cell A2 = Wk1701
...
Cell A8 = Wk1702

I do receive an error for the below so I'm open to opinions.

```
Sub Button1()

For y = 1 To 1092
For w = 1 To 52
For x = 17 To 19
    Cells(y, 1) = "WK" & x & w
        Next y
    Next w
Next x

End Sub
```

Aaron

Comment: "*I do receive an error*" What error? Not really sure how to help when we don't know what error you're having

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you have dates that these week numbers are associated with?  Could you just use code such as `Cells(y, "A") = "WK" & Format(Cells(y, "B"),"yy") & Right("00" & Format(Cells(y, "B"),"ww"), 2)` to achieve what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loops must be fully nested, you cannot loop an outer loop from inside an inner.

`y` does not need to be a loop just a counter.

Then we just assign the same value to a block of 7 cells.

We use `Format(x,"00")` to turn `1` into `01`.

Also assign the parent to the range objects even if it it ActiveSheet:

```
Sub Button1()
dim y As Long, w As Long, x As Long,rws as Long
y = 1
For x = 17 To 19 
    For w = 1 To 52
        ActiveSheet.Cells(y, 1).Resize(7,1).Value = "WK" & Format(x,"00") & Format(w,"00")
        y = y + 7
    Next w
Next x

End Sub
```

To be even quicker use arrays instead of referencing the worksheets so many times:

```
Sub Button1()
Dim y As Long, w As Long, x As Long, z As Long, rws as Long
Dim OtA() As Variant
rws = (19-17+1)*52*7
ReDim OtA(1 To rws, 1 To 1) As Variant
y = 1
For x = 17 To 19
    For w = 1 To 52
        For z = 1 To 7
            OtA(y, 1) = "WK" & Format(x, "00") & Format(w, "00")
            y = y + 1
        Next z
    Next w
Next x
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(OtA, 1)).Value = OtA
End Sub
```

Comment: Argh - the dreaded `&` type hint!  Mat's Mug will spot that, and then you will be in trouble!

Comment: @YowE3K really? did not know it was a no-no.  Why?

Comment: Partly because it is a hang-over from the very early days when that was the only way to type variables, but (I assume) mainly because it requires people remembering what each of the special characters actually means. :D

Comment: He'll probably pick up on the use of `3` instead of `(19 - 17 + 1)`, or even the use of the literals `17` and `19` instead of having them as constants so that there is only a single place to change them. ;)

Comment: Thanks Scott absolutely spot on! Seams so easy looking back on it.

Cheers buddy!

Comment: @azman1983 please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.